# How to show ajax result in v-menu content on mouse over?

Tags: vuetify.js

I have v-menu attached icons on my page.

I want to show detail info on mouse over of any icon (like tooltip).

But, content should be dynamically get with ajax request.

How can I trigger ajax request on mouse over and show result on `v-menu` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**

using v-menu with open-on-hover shall be enough for that purpose

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [{name: 'php', menu: false, url: 'https://api.mocki.io/v1/b043df5a' }, {name: 'mysql', menu: false, url: 'https://api.mocki.io/v1/b043df5a'}, {name: 'vuejs', menu: false, url: 'https://api.mocki.io/v1/b043df5a'}],
    fav: true,
    message: false,
    hints: true,
    serverTooltips: []
  }),
      watch: {
        items: {
          deep: true,
          handler: function (val) {
          console.log(val)
          val.map((item) => {
            if (item.menu === true) {
              axios.get(item.url).then(({data}) => {
              this.serverTooltips = data
            })
            }
          })
        },
      }
   }, 
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <div class="text-h4">Please mouse over those buttons to see events in Cities</div>
<p>Main code is copied from <a href='https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#popover-menu'>vuetify popover-menu example</a></p>

<div class="mb-2" v-for="item in items">
  <v-menu v-model="item.menu"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          :open-on-hover="true"
          :nudge-width="200" 
          offset-x>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn 
             color="indigo" 
             dark 
             v-bind="attrs" 
             v-on="on">
        Mouse over to see  {{ item.name }} events
      </v-btn>
    </template>

      <v-card v-if="serverTooltips.length">
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/john.jpg" alt="John">
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>Detail for {{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>Detail subtitle</v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-btn :class="fav ? 'red--text' : ''" icon @click="fav = !fav">
                  <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-list>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-switch v-model="message" color="purple"></v-switch>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-title>Enable messages</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>

            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-switch v-model="hints" color="purple"></v-switch>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-title>Enable hints</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>

          <div  v-if="serverTooltips.length">
            {{ item.name }} located in cities:
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item v-for="(tooltip, index) in serverTooltips" :key="index">
                <v-list-item-title>{{ tooltip.city }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </div>
          <p v-else>Fetching data, please wait!</p>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn text @click="menu = false">
              Cancel
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="menu = false">
              Save
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
  </v-menu>
</div>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Anyway I advise you to cache your json information because hover event may be a little aggressive, specially if you're using mobile data.

Comment: I'm using Vuetify 2.4.3. This is my pen: https://codepen.io/vedia/pen/qBqEVeN